# HTML5:Parallax effect and navigation bar. Problem with headers

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website with a navigation bar and parallax effect,but i have a problem. Navigation bar and parallax effect use the same header in body and i wish to know how i can use multiple headers on a page. Can you add please a code example with multiple headers that can be edited separated in CSS?
I will atach down my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Ce inseamna o cariera in it si tech?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body>
    
    <header class="navigation-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src = "IT & TECH.png" width = 200px height = 99px >
            </div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cum sa incepi o cariera?</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>

</html>
```

PS I tried with header1 and header2 but i can't edit them in CSS file.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to use the header with class `navigation-bar` in your parallax effect, or another header?

Comment: Also, it is perfectly valid to use _multiple_ `header` elements on a single page. You can have a `<header>` inside a sidebar, a footer, or even inside any `<div>` on your document. You just need to assign them different classes and you can select them in your CSS. Or you can use parent-descendant selectors to select a header inside another element, for example, an `<aside>` element, like this: `aside header{ YOUR RULES HERE}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use section instead of nav or header and assign id/class for it may be it will help